# Rotating Camera around Character based on circular Touch Motion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am stuck on this problem for a while now. I have a character and a camera that follows that character on the map. The camera is connected to a empty object that follows the position of the character so that the rotation of that object is enought to get a orbit movement. I want the user to be able to rotate that empty object (and with that the camera) with a circular touch motion around the character. I have it working with a horizontal swipe but i cant figure out any way to get a smooth rotation based on a circular touch path. I also can't use look at since i do not want the camera to jump to a certain rotation but to rotate the angle between the start and the end touch.

Sorry for any english mistakes and thanks in advance.

Edit: Working Code with horizontal swipe

```
if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 localAngle = transform.localEulerAngles;
            localAngle.y += rotateSpeed * touchZero.deltaPosition.x;
            transform.localEulerAngles = localAngle;
        }
    }
```

And some code from other people i already tried but cant get to work properly:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        Vector2 mp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

        Vector2 dir = mp - (Vector2)transform.position;

        angleTuchandX = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        startAngle = 360 + angleTuchandX;
    }

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector2 mp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

        Vector2 dir = mp - (Vector2)transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - startAngle;

        if (angle < transform.eulerAngles.y)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, angle, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would advice to include some code you have tried into your question, else it might end flagged and removed.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I think you need to first deal with the change in position and then deal with angle. At first glance, it seems you are trying to do both?

Comment: No i don't think so. The position of the camera follows the character (the position of the character is based on the location of the player, it is a location based game). All of that works just fine, it is just the rotation that i can't figure out at all.

Comment: If my memory doesn't fail me, I think the rotation was something like `x' = x*cos(angle) - y*sin(angle)` and `y' = x*sin(angle) + y*cos(angle)`. A good book is `Computer Graphics` by Hearn Baker (I think it was the name).